# Does using a custom query_var create a security hole?

Tags: wp-query, security

Say I put the following code in functions.php

```
function add_my_query_vars($qvars) {
  $qvars[] = "new_var";
  return $qvars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_query_vars');
```

If somebody requests `my.site.com/?new_var=[MALICIOUS CODE]`, can they cause any damage? If not, why not?

**Edit for clarity**: I know that user input should be considered harmful. My question is whether WP vets the data that makes it into $wp_query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of whether you registered `new_var` as a query_var, all GPC data (GET, POST, COOKIE) should be considered tainted. Basically, this data is user input. This means that you will need to clean and validate the data anyway.

Common cleaning methods include casting the variable to a certain type (like integer or string), using a regex to validate strings, etc. Also, if you are accessing `$_GET` data directly, don't forget to do an [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) check first to prevent "undefined index" notices.

**Edit:** In the first place, my answer applies to accessing GPC data via PHP's superglobals. That being said, if you use [`get_query_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to retrieve your variable, as far as I see, you still need to clean the variables you registered yourself. WP will clean its standard query vars, of course. See the `parse_query()` function in `wp-includes/query.php`.

Comment: can you confirm that Wordpress definitely doesn't do any sanitization on variables that make it into the $wp_query?