# WordPress it's cleaning a custom query_var to avoid sql injections?

Tags: security, sql

I am using  `get_query_var` function to get a custom `query_var`. This `query_var` will be used later in to query arguments to retrieve posts with:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

My question is, is it safe if I  use `get_query_var` such as is provided or do I need clean this variable to avoid sql injections?

I've read [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38087/does-using-a-custom-query-var-create-a-security-hole), but it is not entirely clear and also it is old.

Comment: A public query var must be treated as a user input, so you should sanitizing and validate before you use it. The `WP_Query` object will make the arguments safe for database interactions, like preventing SQL injections, but still it is good that you sanitize and validate the user input data against the value you expect.

Comment: I've found this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes

That can help me to sanitize my user input data.

Thank you so much for all.

Special thanks to Pieter Goosen by your help with my grammar.

Comment: Richzendy or @cybmeta, can you write up the solution as an answer?

Comment: yes, what I mean is - can you write that as an answer, not as a comment. :) You get more internet points for that.

Answer (score 3):

In a perfect world, you don't need sanitize your querys because the WordPress ORM avoids sql injections going to the database, but is extremely recommended to clean your input data, particularly if is input data provided by a visitor.

For example, you can use something like this:

```
$name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['name'] );
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'name' => $name,
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

There are a lot of filter functions that can sanitize:

- sanitize_email()
- sanitize_file_name()
- sanitize_html_class()
- sanitize_key()
- sanitize_meta()
- sanitize_mime_type()
- sanitize_option()
- sanitize_sql_orderby()
- sanitize_text_field()
- sanitize_title()
- sanitize_title_for_query()
- sanitize_title_with_dashes()
- sanitize_user()

For more information read:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data